# c# date and time check

Tags: c#, date, time

Hi everyone I'm doing this project and I'm currently stuck.
I have 3 fields both are date and time field and the third is a status field.

I wanted to check if current date and time are = to target date and target time then it returns true else false. this is my current version of the code.

```
*//DateComp is just a date field that checks if date is completed*
if (DateComp != null)
{
return "Complete|#8FBC8F";
}             

   *//TargetDate is the target date field I want to check* 

else if (IsDate(TargetDate)&&(TargetDate < today.Date))
                return "Overdue|#BC8F8F";

else if (IsDate(TargetDate)&&(TargetDate >= today.Date)) 
                return "Pending|#EEE8AA";
else return "Pending|#EEE8AA";
```

Can anyone please help me with it. Don't know how I can check the time as well for it to return true.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it's very hard to understand what you're trying to achieve here, and posting just snippets makes it harder still to understand.

Comment: Sorry, Basically, I want to check the target date and target time from the current date/time. But I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Why are you returning a hash with each type? I presume they are colours, but how are they used? Are you splitting the reply to find the status and the colour? If so you should either return a tuple and save on splitting, or implement Enums instead of string which map to colours.

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet. I'm confused with the question.

Comment: Hi ben, you are correct. return "Overdue|#BC8F8F" returns a Overdue with red color highlighting the status.

Comment: What does that `IsDate` method do?

Comment: Sorry everyone, All im trying to achieve is how to check the target time. So ATM in my code it checks the date completely but i dont know how I can check the target time so that the field status would return true value based on the target time as well. Does this make sense? sorry

Comment: @BryanAnthonyGarcia IsDate method checks the targetDate field and if its less than current date it returns overdue

Comment: And TargetDate is `DateTime` type?

Comment: @BryanAnthonyGarcia yes i think it is mate, sorry not really good with C# my first week in work and still kinda getting the use to it.

Comment: If you need an IsDate() function to check whether TargetDate is actually a valid date, I wager it is not a DateTime… can you tell us the types of TargetDate and DateComp, and possibly the definition of IsDate()?

Comment: @dumetrulo TargetDate and TargetTime is both date and time field that user fills in to input their target date and time. then I created a status/test field that returns a true or false text when the TargetDate and TargetTime is equals to Todays time and date.

Comment: Rather than describing the code, please - as I said before - provide a [mcve] which shows the problem and *only* the problem.

Comment: Hi john, found the problem the IsDate(TargetDate) function only checks the date of the date field and today.Date checks DATE and TIME which is real time but the system that I am working on is pre set that it only checks the dates and time OVERNIGHT and not real time. and today.Date cant be split? it always return the date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I'm guessing since you've mentioned you want to get the target time, you can use `TargetDate.TimeOfDay` for that. But, if you want to check if they are equal, you can just use the (`==`) operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the equals operator (`==`) to check if the `DateTime` objects are equal.

If you want to know *how* they differ, you can use [`DateTime.CompareTo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: so instead of using TargetDate < today.Date just use == instead?